# How to repeat reading the value from the BLE device only when the value updated (python on MacOS)?

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, device

As title, now I can get values from the BLE device, as the following codes shown:

```
class RobotDelegate(object):
...

def peripheral_didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService_error_(self, peripheral, service, error):
for characteristic in self.service.characteristics():
   if characteristic.UUID() == blebee_characteristic:
        self.characteristic = characteristic
        print ("self.characteristic.value = ", self.characteristic.value())
...

delegate = RobotDelegate()
manager = CBCentralManager.alloc()
manager.initWithDelegate_queue_options_(delegate, None, None)

AppHelper.runConsoleEventLoop()
```

And I can read the value from my BLE device only one time... Actually, the BLE device can continuously update the value when someone touch, so I like to know how should I do to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: You need to use BLE "notifications".

Comment: @Emil Thank you so much for your response! When I tried to google the usage of how to use "peripheral_didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic", but there is almost no any relevant resources or examples. It makes me very hard to start with it. Have you had this kind of experiences before? I think that if there is an example, even a simplest one, can help me a lot. Here is an question, It seems that the command "UpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic()" need to be used first to call back the "peripheral_didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic", am I right? and how to use these two. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the Observer Pattern. An Example can be found [here](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer/python/1). In your case a BLE device would be a 'Subject' and notifies each time, when the value changes.

Comment: Thank you for the response! however I have no idea about how to use "observe" that you recommended. Is there any simple example ? Or do you know how to use "observe" in this kind of cases? Thanks.